# Remap UIWebView root URL to [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, nsbundle

I've got some HTML and some images in my iPhone app, arranged something like:

```
html/
    foo.html
images/
    bar.png
```

I can get `bar.png` to appear in my `UIWebView` a couple of different ways -- either loading `foo.html` from an `NSUrl`, and walking back up the directory tree from the html directory:

```
<img src="../images/bar.png"/>
```

or by loading `foo.html` into a string, using `loadHtmlString`, and using `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]` as the `baseURL`:

```
<img src="images/bar.png"/>
```

Both of these are kind of clumsy, though -- in the first case, if I move HTML files around I have to rejigger all the relative paths, and in the second case, I have to ignore the actual path structure of the HTML files.

What I'd like to make work is this --

```
<img src="/images/bar.png"/>
```

-- treating the `bundleURL` as the root of the "site". Is there any way to make this work, or am I doomed to have that translated into `file:///images/bar.png` and have the file not found?

Comment: I'm looking to do the exact same thing. Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I'll ask, since it's a couple of years later: did you ever find a good way to use root-relative URLs to content in the iOS filesystem? Outside of running a local web server, I haven't found a sane way to do this -- I would even be happy to hack things by rewriting UIWebView's requests, provided there were a place to do so.

Comment: Sadly, no, but I haven't been doing IOS development for a couple of years now.

Comment: @DavePeck I think i see a way to implement this without going for hacks like custom web server :). One need to implement custom schema or a redirection using NSURLProtocol, once i have nice solution i'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you have some files in your project bundle that you want to load in your web view. You can do it simply with these few lines of code:

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bar" ofType:@"png"];
NSURL    *imageURL  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];
```

I'm assuming that you have a text/html file containing the pattern for your web view. You'll need to add the image as an object there (`src="%@"...`) and then add the `imageURL` to the pattern:

```
NSString *path = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"htmlPattern" ofType:@"html"]];
NSError *error;
NSString *pattern = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path 
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                      error:&error];


htmlPage = [[NSString  alloc]initWithFormat:pattern,
            imageURL; 
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:WEBVIEW_FRAME];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlPage baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pattern]]];
```

Comment: Not on this project any more but that looks like the sort of trick that would work. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this addresses the original question, which is asking for a way to use root-relative URLs. If you're coming from the filesystem, root-relative is by definition going to be the root of the filesystem... what you'd like is to somehow rewrite URLs so that the root is where *you'd* like it to be...

Answer (score 1):

Only way I can see for you to do this would be to embed a web server in your app. [Matt Gallagher](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html) has a blog post on this you could start from. Alternatively, [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) and [Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) could be dropped into your project.