# Root folder of webView resources, how to load images without changing src-tag

Tags: ios

I have a few images that are part of a web page which i want to load into a webview. The images are saved locally.

I load the html like this, and everything works well:

```
NSURL *baseUrl = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:myHtmlStringWithImgTags baseURL:baseUrl];
```

The html is displayed correctly.

When my IMG-tags look like this, everything works well:

```
<img src="image.png" />
```

However, I will get these images from html generated by EpiServer, and the img tags will look like this:

```
<img src="/image.png" />
```

I do not want to start parsing the html and remove the absolute path to root at the beginning of the src-tag. How to solve this? What should I have as baseUrl?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Seems to be a common problem:
[Remap UIWebView root URL to [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092205/remap-uiwebview-root-url-to-nsbundle-mainbundle-bundleurl)

Anyone got a solution except starting to hack the html and remove the root-paths?

Comment: try add point `.` to end of base url

Comment: it is a NSURL and not a String. How to add/remove anything but path-components?

Comment: few ways to do this, for example `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[baseUrl.absoluteString stringByAppendingString:@"."]];`

Comment: root path not changed or images still not loads?

Comment: Check my edit for the string-paths

Comment: can you check that dot in base url help you? Add it to src tag in safari debugger and see, if yes we can try to change root path, but if my guess is wrong no reason to dig in this direction